# how to keep selected highlight

Tags: html, highlight

**The process is like this as below.**

- a user choose some text and make selection on it. then it's gonna be highlighted.
- the user move her mouse focus on the textbox on the html.
- the highlight on the text in the html is still there.
- If the user move her mouse back to the text, click somewhere on the text zone, the highlight would be gone.
- The user can make another new highlight.

**Here's my question.**

- Can I keep the highlight even though I change the focus on other object from text in the html?
- I don't want to use span for it since if I want to make new highlight, it's tedious to move the span back out. Is there another way?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/highlighter.html?serializedHighlights=